# How to simplify this using FunctionRange?

Tags: functions, function-construction, simplifying-expressions

This simple function range works fine.

```
In[3832]:= FunctionRange[{1/x,2<= x<=3}, x,y]
Out[3832]= 1/3<=y<=1/2
```

Now If I substitute `2` and `3` by variables `a` and `b` I got a complex result.

```
In[3839]:= FunctionRange[{1/x,a<= x<=b}, x,y]//FullSimplify
Out[3839]= (y<0&&a y>=1&&b y<=1)||(y>0&&a y<=1&&b y>=1)
```

I thought that is reasonable as these variables's values are unknown so I add more conditions with the hope that it'll be simplied as `1/b < y < 1/a` but I couldn't get this.

```
In[3840]:= FunctionRange[{1/x,a<= x<=b, a>0, b>0, b>a }, x,y]//FullSimplify
Out[3840]= a>0&&a<b&&((a y==1&&y<0)||(y>0&&a y<=1&&b y>=1))
```

How can I get the result `1/b < y < 1/a`?

Comment: `FunctionRange[{1/x, a < x < b && a > 0 && b > 0 && a < b}, x, 
  y] // Reduce` ?

Comment: @Syed it works. I tried the same thing but with `FullSimplify` instead. Somehow  `FullSimplify`  is not as good as `Reduce` in this case.